# Substitute `number` with `(number)` in multiple lines

Tags: vim

I am a beginner at Vim and I've been reading about substitution but I haven't found an answer to this question.

Let's say I have some numbers in a file like so:

```
    1
    2
    3
```

And I want to get:

```
    (1)
    (2)
    (3)
```

I think the command should resemble something like `:s:\d\+:.......`. Also, what's the difference between `:s/foo/bar` and `:s:foo:bar` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me address those in reverse.

First: there's no difference between `:s/foo/bar` and `:s:foo:bar`; whatever delimiter you use after the `s`, vim will expect you to use from then on.  This can be nice if you have a substitution involving lots of slashes, for instance.

For the first: to do this to the first number on the current line (assuming no commas, decimal places, etc), you could do

```
:s:\(\d\+\):(\1)
```

The `\(...\)` doesn't change what is matched - rather, it tells vim to remember whatever matched what is inside, and store it.  The first `\(...\)` is stored in `\1`, the second in `\2`, etc. So, when you do the replacement, you can reference `\1` to get the number back.

If you want to change ALL numbers on the current line, change it to

```
:s:\(\d\+\):(\1):g
```

If you want to change ALL numbers on ALL lines, change it to

```
:%s:\(\d\+\):(\1):g
```

Comment: Thanks much N R Peterson. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

Here is an alternative, slightly less verbose, solution:

```
:%s/^\d\+/(&)
```

Explanation:

```
^   anchors the pattern to the beginning of the line
\d  is the atom that covers 0123456789
\+  matches one or more of the preceding item
&   is a shorthand for \0, the whole match
```

Comment: The better solution. Not a fan of escaping parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with:

```
:%s/\([0-9]\)/(\1)/
```

`%s` means global search and replace, that is do the search/replace for every line in the file. the `\( \)` defines a group, which in turn is referenced by `\1`. So the above search and replace, finds all lines with a single digit (`[0-9]`), and replaces it with the matched digit surrounded by parentheses.